# Interpretation of four-vectors on a manifold

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

I have a couple of silly questions related to the concept of manifold. In Euclidean or flat Minkowski space I can easily specify an origin $O$, and then describe the position of a particle at a point $p$ with a four-vector $x^\mu$ . Drawing an arrow from $O$ to $p$ gives me something I can call a tangent vector, because it lives entirely in a space $T_p M\simeq T_OM\simeq M$. Four-position  and any other four-vector can be thus described with their contravariant components, and there is no real difference between the point $p$ and the arrow itself.

In a more complex manifold, this doesn't seem to work. Unless $p$ is infinitesimally close to $O$, there is in general no straight arrow connecting the two points. So, it seems to me that I can't think of the distance from $O$ to $p$, which is what I'm trying to measure, in terms of a single arrow, but rather in terms of several little arrows, each living in its own tangent space.

I'd like someone to clear up the formalism a little. Should I really think about the four-position as a tangent vector?

Answer (score 0):

In Physics (at least at our scale) we believe that physical measurements / interactions are local. In this sense, the point "*unless $p$ is infinitesimally close to $O$*" does matter. Conceptually we, poor human being, can only know what happens around and arrange them in a shelf marked with coordinates. The local coordinates we tend to use are Minkovskian or Eulidean. That is what we usually call "local inertial frame" or equivalence principle in GR. Mathematically, the local inertial frame is defined with a theorem of its existence.

> (**Riemann Coordinates**) For any point $p$ on maniford $\mathcal M$, there is a neiborhood $\mathcal O_p \subset \mathcal M$ that we can establish a bijection $$\exp:T_p\mathcal M\rightarrow\mathcal O_p$$

So the vectors in tengent space are rulers to measure the events around the observer at point $p$.

As for the events happened at distance, indeed we know them by using our logic, as we are trying to deduce what happened in early universe, or by relay, as your roommate came in and tell you that the landlord were coming and asking for host rent. The last case is mathematically modeled as an integral around the path the information passed.

In a word, "*the four-position as a tangenet vector*" is locally true because we always need a ruler in measurement. However we are all "short-sighted" and what we measured is not the whold world.